# How does serialization work without constructors?

Tags: .net, serialization

I'm not sure how this piece of code works.

```
    [Serializable]
    class Blah
    {
        public Blah(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int value;
    }

        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        Blah blah = new Blah(4);
        MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
        b.Serialize(s, blah);
        s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        blah = null;
        blah = (Blah)b.Deserialize(s);
```

As I don't have a parameterless constructor, it seems strange that the deserializer can create a new instance of Blah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deserialization process uses [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx) which gets an object without calling any constructor.

Answer (score 4):

The serializer doesn't call a constructor when it deserializes an object. The values of the fields are set directly. It doesn't need to create the object (via `new`) it just creates storage, fills it, and casts it as a `Blah` type.

Answer (score 1):

`BinaryFormatter` uses voodoo method called [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx):

> ...the object is initialized to zero and no constructors are run